# What's the best way to spell-check a complete Drupal site?

Tags: 7

I'd like to spell-check a complete site (some 300 pages) and my plan is this:

1. Spell-check complete site to collect all misspellings from all pages
2. Make a spelling dictionary to be shared by all editors
3. Rerun spell-check to get list of pages with misspellings
4. Install TinyMCE spell-check module over aspell, using spelling dictionary from 2
5. Get the editors to go over all misspelt pages and fix them

How can I run the complete spell-check in 1 and 3? I can hack it with wget, aspell and perl but is there an easier solution?
Can I present the misspellings from 3 in context, highlighted in the page?

Comment: Hello, Vladimir Alexiev; welcome on _Drupal Answers_. To which Drupal version are you interested?

Comment: AFAIK, we use Drupal 7

Answer (score 3):

I considered CheckDog but then hacked a quick perl script using curl & aspell:

```
#!perl

use constant SITEMAP => "http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml";
use constant MAX_PAGES => 10;

$npages = 0;
for (qx{curl --silent @{[SITEMAP]}}) {
  m{<loc>(.*?)</loc>} or next;
  $page = $1;
  ++$npages > MAX_PAGES and last;
  print "$page\t"; # here so if aspell crashes, we know which page
  $typos = qx{curl --silent $page | aspell --mode=html --home-dir=. --personal=dict.txt list};
  $typos =~ tr{\n}{ };
  print "$typos\n"
}
```

Add valid words to dict.txt, where the first line is:

```
personal_ws-1.1 en 500
```

As per @Berdir and @kiamlaluno suggestion, we'll also try TextReview. The following use cases would be of interest to us:

1. Differences: hopefully better than a module that displays raw html side by side
2. Spell check: showing misspellings in context will be wonderful!
3. Similarity percentage: maybe we can use this to warn on duplicate pages?
4. Manually configured blacklists and whitelists: eg to avoid UK spellings "customise" in favor of US spellings "customize"

Comment: There's much to like about this solution. HOWEVER, how can we force aspell to use utf-8 for both input AND the personal dictionary file? Otherwise it's going to burp on every "You’ve" (curly quotes) etc.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used them, but [Text Review](http://drupal.org/project/trevi) and [Spellcheck](http://drupal.org/project/spellcheck) could be helpful.

Comment: TextReview is not relevant to the question, and SpellCheck is the interactive module described in 4 above

Comment: @Vladimir Alexiev Your last question is "Can I present the misspellings from 3 in context, highlighted in the page?" As far as I can see, that is what Text Review does: "Text Review is a bundle of modules that allows you to **review texts** in a variety of ways and **display the results within the text**."

Comment: Thanks @Berdir, I must be blind. We'll try it and I'll write here how it goes.

Comment: FYI, these modules are unsupported or non-existent under D7